# How to get the user name by using firebase verifyToken()?

Tags: node.js

**Auth Middleware -  where I am performing verifyIdToken()**

```
const admin = require("../firebase");

const authCheck = async(req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const firebaseUser = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authtoken);
        console.log("FIREBASE USER => ", firebaseUser);
        req.user = firebaseUser;
        next();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(422).send({error: e.message});
    }
}
```

**This is the response that I am getting from firebase by using firebase verifyToken(). I am not getting name property. Can anyone tell me how to get the user name?**

```
FIREBASE USER =>  {
  iss: 'https://securetoken.google.com/ecommerce-36c49',
  aud: 'ecommerce-36c49',
  auth_time: 1628002053,
  user_id: '80oOozlXZOVZTLhKAhTMY04YJHC2',
  sub: '80oOozlXZOVZTLhKAhTMY04YJHC2',
  iat: 1628002053,
  exp: 1628005653,
  email: 'robodroid2001@gmail.com',
  email_verified: true,
  firebase: { identities: { email: [Array] }, sign_in_provider: 'password' },
  uid: '80oOozlXZOVZTLhKAhTMY04YJHC2'
}
```

**Updated**

```
const admin = require("../firebase");

const authCheck = async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers.authtoken);
    try{
        const firebaseUser = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authtoken);
        console.log("FIREBASE USER => ", firebaseUser);
        req.user = firebaseUser;
        **const response = await admin.auth().getUser(firebaseUser.uid);
        console.log("response: ", response);**
        next();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(422).send({error: e.message});
    }
}

module.exports = authCheck;
```

**This the the response which I am getting after doing getUser(uid). But still not get name. It is showing name: undefined.**

```
response : UserRecord {
  uid: '80oOozlXZOVZTLhKAhTMY04YJHC2',
  email: 'robodroid2001@gmail.com',
  emailVerified: true,
  displayName: undefined,
  photoURL: undefined,
  phoneNumber: undefined,
  disabled: false,
  metadata: UserMetadata {
    creationTime: 'Tue, 03 Aug 2021 14:46:50 GMT',
    lastSignInTime: 'Tue, 03 Aug 2021 17:28:43 GMT',
    lastRefreshTime: 'Tue, 03 Aug 2021 17:28:43 GMT'
  },
  providerData: [
    UserInfo {
      uid: 'robodroid2001@gmail.com',
      displayName: undefined,
      email: 'robodroid2001@gmail.com',
      photoURL: undefined,
      providerId: 'password',
      phoneNumber: undefined
    }
  ],
  passwordHash: undefined,
  passwordSalt: undefined,
  tokensValidAfterTime: 'Tue, 03 Aug 2021 14:46:51 GMT',
  tenantId: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `uid` after verifying the token you can call `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` and this will return the full user record including `displayName`. But this will only be valid if the `displayName` field was updated when user was created or later on.

Comment: const response = await admin.auth().getUser(firebaseUser.uid);
        console.log(response);                                                                                                                            When I am doing this -> I am still not getting name.  See the updated code.

Comment: Tell me one thing. How we get the user name even we didn't pass any name. We just pass email or password to firebase then how we get the user name too.

Comment: There are 2 ways to get a user's name: if using the password provider you must ask your users at sign up to provide a name and then set that as the `displayName` for the user record. If you are using a 3rd party auth provider (Google, FB, etc) to create new users, the provider will usually supply the user name (as in their systems) in the `displayName` field

Comment: Thank you so much bro now i understand what you are trying to tell me. Thank you so much.... Now I got it.